# subprocess.Popen("ssh host@remote cmd") failed

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm new to python subprocess. When I want to use python subprocess.Popen.communicate to accomplish interact passwd with shell cmd "net ads join -U administrator", it's output didn't redirect into PIPE, but in stdout.My code is under:

```
import subprocess

import os
import sys

passwd = b'123456'
cmd = "net ads join -U administrator"
s1 = ("%s\n" % str(passwd)).encode('utf-8')
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
out,err = p1.communicate(s1)
print(out)
```

When I run the test, communicate didn't work, the output still in the stdout.

```
$ python ads.py 
Enter administrator's password:
```

When I change the cmd to "ssh root@ip ls /", I also met with the problem.

I tried pdb, but the problem seems not here.
Any advise to deal with this problem?

Comment: are you trying to run some command on remote machine using ssh ?

Comment: do you get a chance to read pty module in python, for pseudo terminal.

Comment: I've tried "ssh root@ip ls /" on the remote ip host in bash and Popen, bash is ok, and Popen met the same problem with "net ads .." cmd.

Comment: Ok let me paste a snippet class that I used for remote command run, hope that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet class for SSH and run command remotely, that I used in one of my scripts, please let me know if that works, Here I am using python standard [PTY Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html) for pseudo terminal.

```
import pty
import os 
import re

class BaseError(Exception):
    pass

class SSHError(BaseError):
    pass

class Ssh:

    """SSH on the box"""

    def __init__(self, ip, passwd, user, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.user = user
        self.port = port

    def run_cmd(self, c):
        (pid, f) = pty.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            os.execlp(
                "ssh", "ssh", '-o ConnectTimeout=10',
                '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
                '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-q',
                '-p %d' % self.port,
                self.user + '@' + self.ip, c)
        else:
            return (pid, f)

    def run_scp(self, src, dst):
        (pid, f) = pty.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            os.execlp(
                "scp", "scp", '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
                '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-q',
                '-P %d' % self.port, "-r", src,
                self.user + '@' + self.ip + ':' + dst)
        else:
            return (pid, f)

    def read(self, f):
        x = ""
        try:
            x = os.read(f, 2024)
        except Exception:
            pass
        return x

    def sshOutputs(self, pid, f):

        output = ""
        readOutLoud = self.read(f)
        m = re.search("authenticity of host", readOutLoud)

        if m:
            os.write(f, 'yes\n')
            while True:
                readOutLoud = self.read(f)
                m = re.search("Permanently added", readOutLoud)
                if m:
                    break

            readOutLoud = self.read(f)
        m = re.search("assword:", readOutLoud)

        if m:
            os.write(f, self.passwd + '\n')
            tmp = self.read(f)
            tmp += self.read(f)
            m = re.search("Permission denied", tmp)
            if m:
                raise SSHError("Invalid passwd")
            p = re.search("[pP]assword", tmp)
            if p:
                raise SSHError("Invalid passwd")

            # passwd was accepted
            readOutLoud = tmp

        while readOutLoud and len(readOutLoud) > 0:
            output += readOutLoud
            readOutLoud = self.read(f)

        os.waitpid(pid, 0)
        os.close(f)

        return output

    def exe_ssh_cmd(self, c):
        (pid, f) = self.run_cmd(c)
        return self.sshOutputs(pid, f)

    def exe_scp_cmd(self, src, dst):
        (pid, f) = self.run_scp(src, dst)
        return self.sshOutputs(pid, f)
```

Comment: I tried to execute cmd "ls -l /" on remote host with your snippet.py, it seems good. But when I change the cmd to "net ads join -U administrator", it seems looped in the line:"while readOutLoud". I tried pdb to display the output of read(f) the result is: (Pdb) p readOutLoud
'> /root/snippet.py(24)run_cmd()\r\n-> if pid == 0:\r\n(Pdb) ', instead of the expected: "Enter administrator's password:".

Comment: If you need to retype your admin password after login, then it won't work, you may need to look a cmd which doesn't require to change the user.

Comment: I have changed your run_cmd(self, c) with os.execlp("sh", c), do not need to login.

Comment: Currently I use cmd "net ads join -U Administrator%123456" to avoid the interact with pty. But also thank u